# Create a session scope bean in spring with javax annotations

Tags: java, spring, javax-inject

I am using spring 4, with javax annotations (JSR-330). In maven

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

So I use `@Named`, `@Inject` and `@Resource` from `javax.annotation.*` from `javax.inject.*` instead of Spring `@Autowire`, `@Component` , ... and spring supports them quite well. Good example at: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-and-jsr-330-inject-and-named-example/

My problem is that I can't have a bean in session scope with javax annotation so I used `@Named` and spring `@Scope`: `org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope`

Can I create a session scope bean by using javax annotations ?!

Comment: Please check out my answer. Hope it serves the purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per [this blog](http://derjan.io/blog/2011/10/18/spring-and-jsr-330-scopes/) and the [Official specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330), `JSR 330` does not support scopes like `request` or
>   `session` out of the box. You will have to create your own annotations
>   for this.

Let's look, how to do this for the request scope.

Create your own scope annotation:

```
@Scope
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Request {
}
```

Extend Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver to map your annotation on Spring's scope:

```
public class CustomScopeMetadataResolver extends Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver {

  public Jsr330SpringScopeMetadataResolver() {
    registerScope(Request.class.getName(), WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST);
  }

}
```

Use your custom resolver in your Spring configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package"
  scope-resolver="my.resolver.package.CustomScopeMetadataResolver" />
```

Reference Credit: [Spring and JSR 330 scopes](http://derjan.io/blog/2011/10/18/spring-and-jsr-330-scopes/)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Annotation: `@SessionScoped`

Example:

```
@SessionScoped
public class DukesBday{
...
}
```

Comment: `SessionScoped` is part on spring annotations